# Closing any open userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

After a good search and some (over)thinking I came to the conclusion that I have no answer on what seems to be a simple question.

I have an excel document with many (20+) userforms in it. If you press a button (that is not in the userform, but just on the excel sheet) to start over again it should close any userform that's open at that moment.

I tried with `unload me` but of course I got an error when there wasn't any open userform. 
Then I tried to add `on error resume next` thinking it would skip the line if there was no userform and therefore not giving an error but just continue what I want it to do. (opening a new userform).

It did indeed not give me the error anymore but it doesn't close any open userform as well (when there is one open).

So here I am, hoping someone here can help me as I don't know what to do. I could list up all of the userforms I suppose but it should be possible to go faster and automatically I suppose?

Some more info: It is never possible to have more than one userform open at the same time. // The button I want to create closes all the userforms if there are any and leads the user back to the main menu.

Thanks in advance! 
KawaRu

Comment: `Unload Me` won't work because `Me` is only in-scope *within* the UserForm's code module. So a button on a worksheet cannot invoke `Unload Me`, because there is no `Me` to unload :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the following when you want to unload all forms

```
Sub UnloadAllForms(Optional dummyVariable As Byte)
'Unloads all open user forms
    Dim i As Long
    For i = VBA.UserForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Unload VBA.UserForms(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this works!
Does this only count the open userforms? Starting from 0? Is that why you do `VBA.UserForms.Count - 1`

Comment: This only counts the open userforms and yes exactly the first userform will be 0

Answer (score 0):

This is hopefully the worst code that I have written in the last 5 years, but it will close any breathing form in Excel that you may have (and will kill any variables etc) :

```
Public Sub CloseAll()
    End
End Sub
```

Use with caution!

[From the MSDN End Statement:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/end-statement)

- The `End` statement stops code execution abruptly, without invoking the `Unload`, `QueryUnload`, or `Terminate` event, or any other Visual Basic code.
- Code you have placed in the `Unload`, `QueryUnload`, and `Terminate` events offorms and class modules is not executed.
- Objects created from class modules are destroyed, files opened using the Open statement are closed, and memory used by your program is freed.
- Object references held by other programs are invalidated.
- The `End` statement provides a way to force your program to halt. For normal termination of a Visual Basic program, you should unload all forms.
- Your program closes as soon as there are no other programs holding references to objects created from your public class modules and no code executing.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't want to execute the following code as well. So that's not really a sollution, but anyway, didn't know this so thank you :)

Comment: @KawaRu - what do you mean by "doesn't want"?

Comment: I mean that it really stops at end and doesn't continue with other code.

Comment: @KawaRu - this is the idea of `End`. It stops & kills anything. It is rather useful sometime.

Comment: Like using a sledge hammer to crack a walnut.  It works but there's no edible walnut.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - the idea is to close the forms and not do something further with any of the code.